# Поиск по файлам csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск

Сейчас работал с задачками на `python` с поиском чего либо. Если нужно было найти что-то в файле, то использовал что-то типа: открыть файл, забить в переменную чтение файла, а потом перебирал, и если нужное мне слово было в файле, то выводил на экран. Но не могу реализовать следующую задачу:
есть ряд файлов `csv` формата, называются они `093`, `063`, `053`.
В них первый столбик номер телефона, второй имя и нужно вывести на экран, если заданный номер есть в одном из файлов. Помогите с реализацией плиз.

Comment: Приведите пару строчек CSV файла в качестве примера... Имена и телефоны лучше анонимизировать...

Comment: @MaxU Не обязательно, они были рандомно сделаны авто заполнением, это просто задачка, а не бд телефонов.
Столбец A(930000001
930000010
930000017
930000029
930000056) Столбец B (Dima
Vanya
Sasha
Andrey
Vitya)

Comment: @MaxU Они идут без 0 в начале, эксэль не позволяет просто. Это не проблема, главное реализация поиска по файлам в зависимости он первых 3х цифр 093 053 063

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

def read_them_all(files, **kwargs):
    return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs) for f in files], ignore_index=True)

p = Path(r'/path/to/directory/with/csv')

phones = [930000017, 930000056]
df = read_them_all(p.glob('*.csv'))
print(df.query("A in @phones"))
```

---

Проверил на двух маленьких CSV файлах:

1.CSV:

```
A,B
930000001,Dima
930000010,Vanya
```

2.CSV:

```
A,B
930000017,Sasha
930000029,Andrey
930000056,Vitya
```

Тест:

```
In [43]: p = Path(r'D:\temp\.data\787286')

In [44]: df = read_them_all(p.glob('*.csv'))

In [45]: df
Out[45]:
           A       B
0  930000001    Dima
1  930000010   Vanya
2  930000017   Sasha
3  930000029  Andrey
4  930000056   Vitya

In [46]: phones = [930000017, 930000056]

In [47]: print(df.query("A in @phones"))
           A      B
2  930000017  Sasha
4  930000056  Vitya
```

Comment: ValueError: No objects to concatenate
выдает ошибку

Comment: Проблема в путях похоже? у меня в папке с запускающимся файлом лешит папка с csv. путь выглядит p = Path(r'/csv') верно?

Comment: @kkkkkkkk, `p = Path(r'/path/to/csv_directory')`

Comment: относительно файла сборщика или чего?  написал путь но не работает :/

Comment: @kkkkkkkk, если не знаете как указать относительный путь - укажите абсолютный (полный) путь...

Comment: В том то и проблема, путь указан верно но программа все равно выдает эту ошибку 
ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Comment: @kkkkkkkk, эта ошибка возникает если в указанной директории отсутствуют `.csv` файлы...